# I am getting an error regarding std::istream and int x

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 

int sqr ( int x ) //sqr means square of x 
{

    return x * x ;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::cout << "enter ur number";
    int x ;
    std::cin >>   sqr (x) ;
    std::cout << "square of ur number is : " << sqr  ;
        return 0 ;
}
```

I just started with C++ 2 days back and while trying doing some problems I am now stuck. Please tell me what's the problem, and make the answer understandable because I'm new to the language and might not understand certain terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read into a variable:

```
std::cin >> x;
```

but you can output the value of any (suitably typed) expression:

```
std::cout << sqr(x);
```

Comment: You cannot read "only into a variable": `std::cin >> id(x)` works just as well for a suitable function `id`...

Comment: so can u suggest me where do i have to change my code ...sorry for being such a noob

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed, you can read into any _lvalue_ expression that denotes a suitably typed variable. I'll stick to the abridged version to answer this question.

Comment: @DeepakDahiya: I already did. Change `>> sqr(x)` to `>> x`, and `<< sqr` to `<< sqr(x)`, as the answer says.

Comment: thnxx bro it worked ...stuck with it for last one hour

Comment: @DeepakDahiya:- If this answer helped you then you can accept the answer(A right tick mark turns green when clicked)

Comment: @RahulTripathi where can i find that tick mark sir ?

Comment: @DeepakDahiya:- Perfect. Always do that when  the answer helps you as that would help other facing the same issue in future

Comment: @RahulTripathi okay sir will keep that in mind

Comment: @DeepakDahiya:- Hey dont call me Sir. I am just another guy. Happy coding!

Comment: @RahulTripathi if u will go through some of the comments u will notice few of them got angry with me for being too casual and calling everyone bro thats why i started using sir

Comment: @DeepakDahiya: It's not an "either"/"or" situation. :P "Bro" is extremely casual/chummy (and, at least in my country, a little insulting) and "sir" is a cultural thing: outside of India it sort of reads weirdly, but that's no reason not to use it. So I think the two conversations are unrelated. Also, I never got "angry"! Cheers.